# Taking Elements From a List

Tags: python, list

I want to take an element of a list and remove the final character. The overall aim being to convert the number remaining from `str` to `int` for an equation. I thought this:

```
hand = ['1D', '5S', '10H']
first_card = hand [0]
first_card [:-1]
print [first_card]
```

...was the way to do so, but apparently not.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Frazer

Comment: line 3: `first_card [:-1]` doesn't modify the `first_card` object. It returns a value which has to be caught using assignment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be accomplished for all elements with a list comprehension.

```
>>> hand = ['1D', '5S', '10H']
>>> hand2 = [i[:-1] for i in hand]
>>> hand2
['1', '5', '10']
```

You can also easily convert this to ints at the same time:

```
>>> handints = [int(i[:-1]) for i in hand]
>>> handints
[1, 5, 10]
```

Comment: Thank you Brien. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In case if the string contains multiple characters towards the ending.

```
from itertools import takewhile
map(lambda x: "".join(list(takewhile(lambda x: x.isdigit(),x))), ['1D', '5S', '10H'])
```

Or using a list comprehension

```
[int("".join(list(takewhile(lambda x: x.isdigit(),x)))) for x in ['1D', '5S', '10H']]
```

Answer (score 1):

use `map` to solve trivial operations on every element in a list:

```
list(map(lambda x: x[:-1],hand))
```

Comment: Since the advent of generator expressions in 2.4, `map` is mostly obsolete due to being unreadable.